# How to open a second report from original on ssrs

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I would like to create a report like this:

[image: Report 1]

I have a column called "`hatalar`". And if I click data in "`hatalar`" column,
I would like to open a new report.

New report should be like this:
[image: New report]

How can I open a new report when I click data in report?

Comment: You can use an action to create a link to another report.

Comment: See if this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/drillthrough-reports-report-builder-and-ssrs

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways to do this, open in new window or 'drill through' to the next report in question.

- **New window**: Create a javascript expression that checks whether the report is rendered as a report or excel/pdf and creates a link that will open a new window with the correct URL:

  =IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "RPL",         "javascript:void(window.open('http://myrshost/ReportServer?/AdventureWorks 2008R2/Employee_Sales_Summary_2008R2&ReportMonth=" & Fields!ReportMonthId.Value & "','_blank'))", "http://myrshost/ReportServer?/AdventureWorks 2008R2/Employee_Sales_Summary_2008R2&ReportMonth=" & Fields!ReportMonthId.Value)

Additional MS documentation on how to pass report parameters via the report URL can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/pass-a-report-parameter-within-a-url) but the gist is like this:

Native Mode URL:

```
http://myrshost/ReportServer?/AdventureWorks 2008R2/Employee_Sales_Summary_2008R2&ReportMonth=3&ReportYear=2008
```

SharePoint Mode URL:

```
http://myspsite/subsite/_vti_bin/reportserver?http://myspsite/subsite/AdventureWorks 2008R2/Employee_Sales_Summary_2008R2.rdl&ReportMonth=3&ReportYear=2008
```

- **Drillthrough**: Set the action of the hatalar textbox to 'drillthrough' and pass report parameters.  This will result in the current page being replaced with the sub page.

[Additional documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/drillthrough-reports-report-builder-and-ssrs) can be found on the MS documentation page for drillthroughs.